# How to send window.location.pathname inside the firebase auth email?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send an auth link with the firebase.
Here are the codes on the firebase doc.

```
export const CODE_SETTINGS = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/finishedSignUp',
  handleCodeInApp: true,
};
```

Here is my mail sending function. Its accept the email I need to send the email to.

```
export const startEmailAuth = (email: string) => {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, ACTION_CODE_SETTINGS)
    .then(function(result) {
      // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
      // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
      // if they open the link on the same device.
      window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
      // TODO: make a nicer UI here.
      alert(`Verification email has been sent to ${email}`);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

my question is that if i change the code to something like this.

```
export const startEmailAuth = (email: string, location: string) => {

   firebase ......
}
```

Where should i put the location to be able to send the location together with email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you should pass the "continue url" value in the `actionCodeSettings` Object that you pass as second argument of the `sendSignInLinkToEmail()` method, see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sendsigninlinktoemail).

More precisely, you need to assign this value to the `url` property of the `actionCodeSettings` Object. Use `window.location.pathname` to build this value.

```
  export const startEmailAuth = (email: string, location: string) => {
    const ACTION_CODE_SETTINGS = {
      url: location,
      // ....
    };

    firebase
      .auth()
      .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, ACTION_CODE_SETTINGS)
      .then(function (result) {
        // ...
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: since i am sending the passwordless signin email link.
the url i am using now `http://localhost:3000/finishedSignUp` is the verification path for the email. What I am doing now on the path is just redirecting to the homepage.

What I want is if i try to login from `home/something` I wanted to redirect to that page

Comment: You can redirect to any page in your app, in which you should implement what is described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page. **As said in the doc, the domain of this "any page" must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.**